# PHP: Replace specified tag values in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Take a look at the HTML example below:

```
<iframe width="AnyNumber" height="AnyNumber">
```

How can i replace AnyNumber with specified number $1 and $2 for width and height?
they can be swapped like:

```
 <iframe height="AnyNumber" width="AnyNumber">
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you generating the HTML or are you parsing it and trying to replace some values? (As for attribute order: it doesn't matter.)

Comment: If you want to echo PHP variables in HTML, you do something like <iframe width="<?php echo $1; ?>" height="<?php echo $2; ?>">

Answer (score 0):

It reminds me of templates.

For example you have you html files like this

```
<div class="nav">@navigationMenu</div>
    <img src="@imgSrc">
    <span>@title</title>
    <p>@article</p>
```

and then with a simple php class you replace with the desired values, for example:

```
$this->registry->main_layout->set('imgSrc', './img/green.jpg');
```

There are many tutorials along with the source code (usually a single-simple php class) that implement this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$exmpl = '<iframe width="AnyNumber" height="AnyNumber">';
$exmpl = preg_replace('/(<iframe.*?width=").*?"/',  "\${1}$argv[1]\"", $exmpl);
$exmpl = preg_replace('/(<iframe.*?height=").*?"/', "\${1}$argv[2]\"", $exmpl);
```

Answer (score 0):

$exmpl = 'iframe width="AnyNumber" height="AnyNumber">';

$exmpl = str_replace('width="AnyNumber"','width="'.$1.'"',$exmpl);

$exmpl = str_replace('height="AnyNumber"','width="'.$2.'"',$exmpl);